# .NET 4.5 HttpTaskAsyncHandler upload a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.5

I am trying to work out how to use the new asp.net 4.5 async handlers as well as the Request.GetBufferlessInputStream to write a image upload out to disk. This code runs and it writes a file out but the image is corrupt and I am not sure why. Here is the code I am using

```
public class UploadHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
{
    public override Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Gets a Stream object that can be used to read the 
        // incoming HTTP entity body, optionally disabling the
        // request-length limit that is set in the MaxRequestLength property.

        // This method provides an alternative to using the 
        // InputStream property. The InputStream property waits until the
        // whole request has been received before it returns a Stream object. 
        // In contrast, the GetBufferlessInputStream method returns
        // the Stream object immediately. 
        // You can use the method to begin processing the 
        // entity body before the complete contents of the 
        // body have been received.
        // The entity body (or as much of it as you request and has
        // been received) is returned only when you use the object that 
        // is returned by this method to read the stream, by calling 
        // methods such as the Read method. You use parameters of the 
        // Read method to specify how much of the entity body to read.

        // This method can be useful if the request is uploading a 
        // large file and you want to begin accessing the file contents
        // before the upload is finished. 
        // However, you should only use this method for scenarios where
        // you want to take over all processing of the entity body. 
        // This means that you cannot use this method from an .aspx page, 
        // because by the time an .aspx page runs, the entity body 
        // has already been read.

        using (Stream input = context.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true))
        using (var file = new FileStream("C:\\myfile.jpg", FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
        {
            input.CopyTo(file);
        }

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        return context.Response.Output.WriteAsync("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Further to the above, try it with a large text file. that way the result will be accessible but you can see whats happening to the file.

Comment: I'm thinking that I will have to parse the actual Request and look for the form/multipart data?

Comment: @superlogical: You should move a lot of the information in the comments into the actual question; it overshadows the code and hinders the readability of the question.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having similar problems when using GetBufferlessInputStream which are not present if InputStream is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there is an easy way to handle this now using ASP.NET Web Api!

Read about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Use one of these bad boys [MultipartFormDataStreamProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatastreamprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

not really trying your code out I noticed one thing.  Shouldn't your `Response.ContentType = image/gif` also should the stream be a BinaryStream instead of a regular stream since it's an Image that you are working with..?

Comment: Response.ContentType should be text/plain because I am asynchronously writing writing "Done" as the response to the browser.